# Object not serializable on Windows XP

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, serialization

I made both a client and a service using C# and WCF. They work perfectly on all the modern OS i could try, both x86 and x64.

Now, when trying it on Windows XP it doesnt' work because of this error:

> Type 'System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1[MyObject[]]' cannot be serialized.
>   Consider marking it with the DataContractAttribute attribute, and
>   marking all of its members you want serialized with the
>   DataMemberAttribute attribute

On my service interface i used this

```
[OperationContract()]
List<MyObject> GetFileList(string randomString, string uniqueID);
```

And `MyObject` looks like this

```
[Serializable()]
public class MyObject
{
    public string oneRandomWorld { get; set; }
    public string helloImAVariable { get; set; }

    public SingleVMFileInfo(string oneRandomWorld, string helloImAVariable)
    {
        this.oneRandomWorld = oneRandomWorld;
        this.helloImAVariable = helloImAVariable;
    }
}
```

only strings are contained inside. I tried to extend `MyObject` with those two methods

```
//Deserializer
public MyObject(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext ctxt)
{
    oneRandomWorld = (string)info.GetValue("oneRandomWorld", typeof(string));
    helloImAVariable = (string)info.GetValue("helloImAVariable", typeof(string));
}

//Serializer
public void GetObjectData(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext ctxt)
{
    info.AddValue("oneRandomWorld", oneRandomWorld);
    info.AddValue("helloImAVariable", helloImAVariable);
}
```

without any different result.
This works from Windows 7, 8, 8.1, Server 2008R2, Server 2012, Server 2012 R2.. but give that error on Windows XP and Windows Server 2003.

I'm a little short of ideas, what can i try?

Comment: Do you have any theories of why it's trying to Serialize a `System.Threading.Tasks.Task<MyObject>` rather then just a `MyObject` - else could you include the code that performs the serialisation. serialising a `Task<T>` will always fail because it contains an `Exception` which in turn contains a `Dictionary` which is unserialisable.

Comment: thank you, i'm trying to figure out why..

btw, i'd like to know why the downvote by the one who did it :)

Comment: Could you include the code that serializes your object. there's a good chance we'll find the issue there.

Answer (score 1):

I finally solved this issue editing my `generatedProxy.cs`, the one i created with `svcutil.exe`

That file included, for every function, both the **sync** and **async** version. Even if i didn't ever use any async version the program still tries to initialize it and result in fail.

Deleting **all the aSync versions** fixed my issue.

I still can't understand why only Windows XP and Windows Server 2003 don't like this, but this is how i made it work.

Thank you Dead.Rabit for the information, without it i couldn't ever imagine the problem!

ps: i still can't understand why i got a downvote.. well, i gotta live with it! :)